# Are there power points in Dubai International Airport, UAE (DXB)?

Tags: power, dxb

I've 7 hour layover in DXB Terminal 3, and was wondering if there are universal power points located conveniently around the terminal.

If so, are they usually crowded?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think there are some power points. I am not sure on where you are coming from but you might need a power adaptor. If you don't have one, you could easily find one in the shops there. The power plug in Dubai delivers 220 V with Type G UK style plug.

Answer (score 0):

No, the plugs are all AED type. They don't have universal plugs. You need converters.